# notepad++ remove character 10 to 20 for example

Tags: text-editor, notepad++

How to remove for example character 10 to 20 in every new line?

For example:

original line:

```
<div id="dot"><a id="69149d5ac2-3"  href="
```

Must look like:

```
<div id="dot"><a href="
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag with mouse. Then hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Done!

[image]

This works in a handful of apps: Visual Studio 2010, Word, and more.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Macros. but p.campbell's method is awesome.